# kubuntu 14.04 - do not show window in start panel when on another desktop

Tags: kubuntu, virtual-desktop

I use kubuntu 14.04 and I have configured 4 virtual desktop.
When I go from a virtual desktop to another, I'd like to not see the programs opened on the first desktop on the start bar.
Is it possible ? I could not find it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this on KDE 5 Plasma, I am sure this feature is available on KDE 4too.
Right click on Task bar (it is in between System Tray and Application Start Menu) the click on **Task Manager Settings** then check **Show only tasks from the current desktop** option

[image: KDE 5 Plasma 'show tasks from current desktop']